# How can I optmize a "select all" statement in linq that casts ~4000 rows to objects?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a method doing some linq operations that is taking over a minute to take 4,000 rows from SQL and place them into a list of objects. What I am trying to do can be summed down to:

1. Get all rows from table
2. Cast each row to a corresponding object based on the rows fields
3. Return a list of that object

In other words, I have an object that corresponds to a row in my database and I want linq to return back a list of all the objects in the table those rows sit in.

What I'm doing is this:

```
public List<Article> GetAllArticlesFromDB()
    {
        using (DBEntities le = new DBEntities(this._efConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<ARTICLE> x = from row in le.ARTICLE select row;

            List<Article> llr = x.Select(r => new Article
            {
                 ArticleNumber = r.ARTICLE_NUMBER,
                 ArticleTitle = r.TITLE,
            }).ToList();

            return llr;
        }
    }
```

Trouble is, this query takes over a minute. There are only two fields, one is an int, the other a string of max length 255. A simple SQL query on it works in less than a second. But this linq query takes over a minute. Can I optimize this somehow?

Comment: Does `Article` constructor or property setters do complex stuff?

Comment: Something is not right here. This should complete within milliseconds. There is some hidden code here that is slowing everything down.

Comment: You cannot optimize the **Linq** statement, this one is just OK. You can optimize the **Entity Framework** usage which ist much more important

Comment: Is `List<Article>` a requirement or would `IEnumerable<Article>` be acceptable?  The switch may not improve overall performance (others have posted useful answers on that front) but might improve time to first result by merit of the lazy evaluation versus the need to materialize as a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which Entity Framework Context approach are you using for your entities? The "old" entity framework approach generates context objects which are all `EntityObject` derived objects and introduce much overhead, and constructing 4000 of them might take quite long. A better approach is to use POCO objects, they are quite small and fast, but you might need to use a [different generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313) if you are using Visual Studio 2010 and/or EF 4 (in contrast to VS 2012 and EF5 which allows generation of POCO entities out of the box).

Which EF Version and which approach are you using?

[Here is a nice tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj206878) showing how to get the new `DbContext` approach (for database first scenarios) working.

Comment: Constructing 4000 objects is *nothing*. It is taking 1min for him to do that.

Comment: @usr I'm just giving tips on how to reduce runtime on c# side since he says that the query is very fast. Maybe there are other things like lazy-loading disabled (causing EF to read all related data), or other reasons. But this was actually accepted and I wonder why. Did it really solve the problems?

Answer (score 0):

Make your database work for you, instead of making the application do everything. Use paging or similar to pull a smaller number of records, as no one will actually view 4000 records at a single time. If you need to filter, again make the database do it.

Does `Article` have a constructor? You should definitely be using the default constructor if you can, since you directly assign properties.

Also, have you tried running it in one statement instead of two? Not sure if that would have better performance, but it's an idea.

i.e.

```
List<Article> llr = (from row in le.ARTICLE
                     select new Article
                     {
                         ArticleNumber = row.ARTICLE_NUMBER,
                         ArticleTitle = row.TITLE
                     }).ToList();
```